# Manual uppercase/lowercase explanation

Tags: javascript

I found the following code in the AngularJS source and have no idea how that works:

```
"this is it.".replace(/[a-z]/g, function(ch) {return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) & ~32);})
```

Will output `THIS IS IT.`

I especially dont understand that part `ch.charCodeAt(0) & ~32` and how it makes an uppercased letter. Anyone could explain to me the logic?

Full code

```
var manualUppercase = function(s) {
  return isString(s)
      ? s.replace(/[a-z]/g, function(ch) {return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) & ~32);})
  : s;
};
```

Comment: Challenge: Break down what you're trying to work out into smaller parts. You don't understand the `~32` part, so research until you end up [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). You don't know what the `charCodeAt()` function does? [Look it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Comment: I understood nothing about that piece of code so I made some researches until I got stuck with the `ch.charCodeAt(0) & ~32` and how it makes a capital.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `~32` takes the value 32 and flips every bit, to give a bit pattern like this: `11011111`.

The ASCII values for upper case letters start at value 65, while those for lowercase start at 97. The difference is bit 5, or 32.

Thus, if you preform a bitwise AND with, say `a` and `~32` , bit 5 will be cleared and the result will be `A`.

Note: this only works for ASCII alphabetic characters. It'll fail miserably for UTF-8 outside that range.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `/[a-z]/` matches each lowercase character between *a* and *z*.

Then, each match is passed to the following function as the argument `ch`, and it is replaced by the returned string.

```
function(ch) {
    return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) & ~32);
}
```

That function works like this:

1. It gets the character code of `ch` with `ch.charCodeAt(0)`. See [`charCodeAt` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).
2. `~32` is `-33`. See [bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7E_%28Bitwise_NOT%29).
3. It does a [bitwise AND operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29) with those numbers.

   This is a trick which, for numbers between 97 (character code of *a*) and 122 (code of *z*), will subtract 32 to them, giving the code of uppercase character.

   For example:

   ```
   Character | Code | Code & ~32 | New character
   ----------------------------------------------
   a         | 97   | 65         | A
   b         | 98   | 66         | B
   c         | 99   | 67         | C
   ```

   You can find the full list of ASCII character codes [here](http://ascii-code.com/).
4. With [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) it converts the code above to the corresponding character
5. It returns that character